# I used the Data Source Configuration Wizard to create a connection to an Access database

Tags: sorting, ms-access, listbox

I used the Data Source Configuration Wizard to create a connection to an Access database and fill a listbox. All is well except the list is not sorted. If I set the sort order via the properties dialog, then the list is  sorted, but the associated textboxes that display information from the database are still sorting in the order  that was defined in the dataset.

I know I need to sort the dataset, but since the Wizard created the connection, I don't know how to find the code. The only code I can find is in the form load section and it is as follows:

`this.membership_LogTableAdapter.Fill(this.membership_Log_DataSet.Membership_Log);`

I tried to manipulate the sort order by doing the following, but it did not work:

`this.membership_Log_DataSet.DefaultViewManager.DataViewSettings["Membership_Log"].Sort = "Last_Name ASC";`

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're filling/binding-to individual datatable. If is the case, try setting sorting of that specific table:

```
this.membership_Log_DataSet.Membership_Log.DefaultView.Sort = "Last_Name ASC";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply; however, it did not work. I copied and pasted your code both above and below the C# generated code in the load section of the form.

Comment: I figured it out. I double clicked the Membership_Log_DataSet.xsd file in the solution explorer and then I right clicked the Fill,GetData method and clicked properties and then I was able to alter the SQL command text by adding ORDER BY Last_Name

Comment: Yes if you could do it at SQL level that's the best solution

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I double clicked the Membership_Log_DataSet.xsd file in the solution explorer and then I right clicked the Fill,GetData method and clicked properties and then I was able to alter the SQL command text by adding ORDER BY Last_Name to the auto-generated SQL code.